# Run-Time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)' Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Workbook' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a useform that will open another work book when opened and close the workbook when closed. This works well the first time, but when I go to open the userform again it shoots out the runtime error. I can use some help on this issue I have not been able to determine what the issue is. Below is the error line in italics:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F3}", "ShowForm"
End Sub

Sub ShowForm()
    *Auto_Fill_Form.Show*
End Sub
```

The button I use to exit the userform is shown below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Workbooks("WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Userform Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

'ComboBox1.Value = ""
Workbooks("WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
        Me.Width = 480
        Me.Height = 520
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label26.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox15.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton7.Visible = True

            Auto_Fill_Form.Label22.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox16.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label23.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox17.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label24.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox18.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label25.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox19.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton8.Visible = False

        TextBox15 = Translate(TextBox10.Value, "en", "es", True)
        SortAsc2

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
     Me.Width = 480
     Me.Height = 520
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label22.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox16.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label23.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox17.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label24.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox18.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label25.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox19.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton8.Visible = True

            Auto_Fill_Form.Label26.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox15.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton7.Visible = False

        TextBox16 = Translate(TextBox11.Value, "en", "es", True)
        TextBox17 = Translate(TextBox12.Value, "en", "es", True)
        TextBox18 = Translate(TextBox13.Value, "en", "es", True)
        TextBox19 = Translate(TextBox14.Value, "en", "es", True)

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table15").Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", _
After:=rng.Cells(1), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox10.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = TextBox15.Value
SortAsc2
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").Range
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", _
After:=rng.Cells(1), _
Lookat:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 4).Value = TextBox11.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 5).Value = TextBox12.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Value = TextBox13.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 7).Value = TextBox14.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 8).Value = TextBox16.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 9).Value = TextBox17.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 10).Value = TextBox18.Value
    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 11).Value = TextBox19.Value
SortAsc2
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(1, 9).Value = TextBox1.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("First Piece Inspection").Cells(5, 7).Value = TextBox1.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production Inspection").Cells(5, 7).Value = TextBox1.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(3, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(3, 8).Value = TextBox3.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(4, 8).Value = TextBox4.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(4, 5).Value = TextBox5.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(5, 2).Value = ComboBox1.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(10, 1).Value = TextBox7.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(10, 3).Value = TextBox8.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(20, 3).Value = TextBox9.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(21, 2).Value = ComboBox2.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(24, 2).Value = ComboBox3.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(27, 2).Value = ComboBox4.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(30, 2).Value = ComboBox5.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(33, 2).Value = ComboBox6.Value
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(36, 2).Value = ComboBox7.Value

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    If OptionButton1.Value Then
        Me.Width = 375
        Me.Height = 520
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label17.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox10.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton5.Visible = True

            Auto_Fill_Form.Label18.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox11.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label19.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox12.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label20.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox13.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label21.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox14.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton6.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.Width = 250
        Me.Height = 520
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label17.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox10.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton5.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
 If OptionButton2.Value Then
        Me.Width = 375
        Me.Height = 520
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label18.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox11.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label19.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox12.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label20.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox13.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label21.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox14.Visible = True
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton6.Visible = True

            Auto_Fill_Form.Label17.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox10.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton5.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.Width = 250
        Me.Height = 520
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label18.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox11.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label19.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox12.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label20.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox13.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label21.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox14.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton6.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

TextBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(1, 9).Value
TextBox2.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(3, 2).Value
TextBox3.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(3, 8).Value
TextBox4.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(4, 8).Value
'TextBox5.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(4, 5).Value

ComboBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(5, 2).Value

TextBox7.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(10, 1).Value
TextBox8.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(10, 3).Value
TextBox9.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(20, 3).Value

ComboBox2.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(21, 2).Value
ComboBox3.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(24, 2).Value
ComboBox4.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(27, 2).Value
ComboBox5.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(30, 2).Value
ComboBox6.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(33, 2).Value
ComboBox7.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WO_Cover").Cells(36, 2).Value
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label17.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox10.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label18.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox11.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label19.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox12.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label20.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox13.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label21.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox14.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton5.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton6.Visible = False

            Auto_Fill_Form.Label26.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox15.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton7.Visible = False

            Auto_Fill_Form.Label22.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox16.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label23.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox17.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label24.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox18.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.Label25.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.TextBox19.Visible = False
            Auto_Fill_Form.CommandButton8.Visible = False
'TextBox10.Value =

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty Form
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
ComboBox1.Value = Null

'Initialized value
TextBox5.Value = "A"
ComboBox2.Value = "N/A"
ComboBox3.Value = "N/A"
ComboBox4.Value = "N/A"
ComboBox5.Value = "N/A"
ComboBox6.Value = "N/A"
ComboBox7.Value = "N/A"

Me.ComboBox1.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table15").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
Me.ComboBox2.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
Me.ComboBox3.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
Me.ComboBox4.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
Me.ComboBox5.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
Me.ComboBox6.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
Me.ComboBox7.List = Locations.Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value


TextBox7.Value = ""
TextBox8.Value = ""
TextBox9.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Module 1:

```
Private wLocations As Workbook

Public Const Page = "Description - Processes"

Public Property Get Locations() As Workbook
  Const sPath As String = "V:\My Stuff\Templates\Work Order Batch Creation Template\WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm"
  Dim sFile As String

  If wLocations Is Nothing Then
      'extract file name from full path
      sFile = Dir(sPath)

      On Error Resume Next

      'check if the file is already open
      Set wLocations = Workbooks(sFile)

      If wLocations Is Nothing Then
        Set wLocations = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
      End If

      On Error GoTo 0
  End If
  Set Locations = wLocations
End Property
```

Module 2:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F3}", "ShowForm"
End Sub

Sub ShowForm()
    Auto_Fill_Form.Show
End Sub
```

Module 3:

```
Sub SortAsc2()

    Locations.Worksheets(Page).Range("A2:B16").Sort Key1:=Locations.Worksheets(Page).Range("A2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Locations.Worksheets(Page).Range("D2:K16").Sort Key1:=Locations.Worksheets(Page).Range("D2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'    Locations.Worksheets("Description - Processes").Range("A2:B16").Sort Key1:=Locations.Worksheets("Description - Processes").Range("A2"), _
'    Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
'    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
'
'    Locations.Worksheets("Description - Processes").Range("D2:K16").Sort Key1:=Locations.Worksheets("Description - Processes").Range("D2"), _
'    Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
'    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

Module 4:

```
Public Function Translate(strInput As String, strFromLanguageCode As String, strToLanguageCode As String, blnTargetAlphabet As Boolean) As String

    Dim strURL As String
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim objHTML As Object
    Dim objDivs As Object, objDiv
    Dim strTranslatedT0 As String
    Dim strTranslatedO1 As String

    ' send query to web page
    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromLanguageCode & _
        "&sl=" & strFromLanguageCode & _
        "&tl=" & strToLanguageCode & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ""

    ' create a html document
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        .Close
    End With

    ' o1 has Anglicised translation, t0 as tranlsation in target language
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        If objDiv.className = "o1" Then
            strTranslatedO1 = objDiv.innerText
        End If
        If objDiv.className = "t0" Then
            strTranslatedT0 = objDiv.innerText
        End If
    Next objDiv

    ' choose which to return
    If blnTargetAlphabet Then
        Translate = strTranslatedT0
    Else
        Translate = strTranslatedO1
    End If

CleanUp:
    Set objHTML = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Are you able to supply the userform code?

Comment: @Davesexcel Any ideas on what is causing the runtime error?

Comment: I don't see where the userform opens another workbook

Comment: @Davesexcel Those are additional modules. I can post those as well. One moment.

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: @Davesexcel Refer to the first paragraph I posted. Right here *Auto_Fill_Form.Show*

Comment: The reason the error shows in that line would be an indication you have an error in the initialize code or activate code. If you can place a stop in the initialize code so you can step through the code to see where it errors.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u94dv2rumi93zvc/AADnFOPJYyDza0yo_OHWB-hpa?dl=0

Comment: @Davesexcel Here is a drop box link. To make this easier. I tried to use the on error resume next but if I did that the for would not open again.

Comment: The problem is in the `Public Property Get Locations() As Workbook`, it skips over this line `Const sPath As String = "V:\My Stuff\Templates\Work Order Batch Creation Template\WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm"` I don't know how to fix it. My assumption is the code does not recognize the workbook is closed.

Comment: @Davesexcel Did you change it to the currently location on your computer? That was my personal directory.

Comment: Yes, like you said, it works the first time, when I closed the userform, it closed the workbook.You can just use a code in the userform initialize code, to open the workbook and collect the data, then close the workbook, instead of having all that confusing code.

Comment: @Davesexcel can you show me I am still new to vba the way I did it was the only way I knew how.

Comment: @Davesexcel I did what you said and removed the module and just manually entered everything now it works no issue. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the workbook to collect the data.
If you close the wb right away, you will have to get rid of the `workbook.close` line in the "Quit" Button

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\TestRemoveLater\WorkOrderDatabase-1.xlsm")

        'Empty Form
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        TextBox4.Value = ""
        ComboBox1.Value = Null

        'Initialized value
        TextBox5.Value = "A"
        ComboBox2.Value = "N/A"
        ComboBox3.Value = "N/A"
        ComboBox4.Value = "N/A"
        ComboBox5.Value = "N/A"
        ComboBox6.Value = "N/A"
        ComboBox7.Value = "N/A"

        With wb
            Me.ComboBox1.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table15").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
            Me.ComboBox2.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
            Me.ComboBox3.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
            Me.ComboBox4.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
            Me.ComboBox5.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
            Me.ComboBox6.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
            Me.ComboBox7.List = .Worksheets(Page).ListObjects("Table24").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value
'.close
        End With

        TextBox7.Value = ""
        TextBox8.Value = ""
        TextBox9.Value = ""
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are a lot of threads on that, your original question has been answered, continuing on with this thread is just going to clutter it.